# better way preventing xss attack

Tags: php, xss

Which of the two is a better way to prevent an xss attack?

1. HTMLEntities while saving in db
2. HTMLEntities while displaying/echoing

I find the first one better because you may forget to add this while displaying.

Comment: And the second might be better as you may forget to do this while saving into the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> which of the two is a better way to prevent xss attack.
>
> 1. HTMLEntities while saving in db
> 2. HTMLEntities while displaying/echoing

2 — you should convert to the target format at the last possible moment. This saves you from problems down the road should you, for example, decide you want to use the same content in an email, a PDF, as text back to the user for editing, etc, etc.

> i find the first one better coz you may forget to add this while displaying

You might forget when inserting into the database too.

Also, not all data goes into the database. e.g. A preview of data about to be inserted or data put back into a form because of errors are both possible XSS vectors. You don't want to be dealing with things like "Encode before putting into the database, or when echoing back into the document if it didn't come from a database". Exceptions are the best way to get yourself into a situation where you forget to encode.

Comment: i meant to add it in before_save function in each model. plz explain a bit more on your last line

Comment: A simple rule like "Convert to HTML when inserting into an HTML document" is better than a complex rule like "Convert to HTML when inserting into an HTML document, and when inserting into an HTML document from `$_POST`, and when inserting to an HTML document from a file".

Comment: i am sorry i still dont get it

Comment: There's no way to simplify it any further.  If you don't get it, you will need to go look up the words that you do not understand.

Comment: @Web Developer Your security rules are way more complex than just "encode properly in rendering code". Complex rules are harder to follow; their implementation is prone to errors and therefore XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: @phihag in cases where i want to show only text is first way better

Comment: @Web Developer I'm not sure about what you mean. Most often, you want the application to be able to handle arbitrary inputs, including `x<y>z`.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons for encoding in the display code (i.e. after reading text from the database):

- The database may be viewed in a non-HTML based GUI that would require modification. Modifying general-purpose database administration tools to automatically decode specific text(in which charset?) for a single application is neither feasible nor desirable.
- Not properly encoding HTML means that you will have to trust the database to be safe. If there is ever a vulnerability – directly in the database or in another web application, your application will become vulnerable too.
- Storing encoded HTML in the database prevents searching; you cannot directly use dedicated searching libraries like Lucene. Also, since html-encoding may not be bijective, full text searches must either operate on a decoded copy of the database or decode all entries in the database, incurring O(database size) performance.
- Future encoding transitions are also way more easier if all the encoding code is concentrated in the display code.
- Encoding increases the occupied storage space

I can't think of any reason for encoding when writing. You mention one may forget to encode data in the displaying logic, but I'd argue you're equally likely to forget it in the database storing code.

Comment: 1. Sure, you should already know the HTML entities, and their meaning, shouldn't you? 2. If you close the gates, and the door of the room, it's hardly for any nasty stuff to get into your room. 3. Why? You could as easily search with entities, couldn't you? 4. Sure, you could always decode the entities and do whatever further encoding transition you like.

Comment: 1. If you encode in display code, a non-HTML based UI does not need any modification, it will just work. But you're right, the other program could apply the equivalent of `html_entity_decode`, if it's not for general database administration. 2. Vulnerabilities in a database need not be exploited from a web application. Sometimes, the database host gets corrupted, or the database password guessed. In terms of your analogy: You'd rather clean up the room before visitors, since you may secure doors and gates, but forget walls and ceilings.

Comment: My question is: what if the database is viewed with an amateurish HTML based GUI?

Comment: 3. No, because the mapping between input and HTML-encoded text is not bijective, you have to decode every single entry in the database. Also, any third-party search tool, like Solr, must be modified before it can be used in conjunction with a database containing HTML-encoded strings. 4. Yes, but that would mean you'd have to shutdown the application, decode and re-encode everything, and then open up the database again. That is not feasible in large-scale distributed deployments.

Comment: @Shef Then there is a security vulnerability in the amateurish HTML based GUI that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @phiag: Sure, after you had opened yourself up. Whereas if you had stripped down and encoded HTML in the first place you would have been protected both ways. Benefits never weight more than protection. So, whatever you mention about searching etc... would never weight more than protection.

Comment: @Shef The amateurish UI could equally be vulnerable to SQL injection; does that mean you must remove SQL injection attempts in database values? Also note that your argument goes both ways: If the amateurish application also stores data in the common database, it creates vulnerabilities in **your** application. Essentially, storing encoded data in the database trades protection of amateurish applications for security in the application itself. Isn't the latter what we were trying to ensure in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The best way(option number 3..) if you ask me is using the latest [filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) extension to handle filtering for you(PHP5). I like to put [filter_input_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) at the top of my php file to protect myself against for example POST XSS attacks

```
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

You should read the filter documentation(tutorials) and protect yourself against XSS for input.

Comment: This is a dangerous practice(misses `GET` and SQL injections) and will not help against a compromised database. Also, it will modify legitimate inputs.

Comment: @phihag I said for example... If you have more(GET,SESSION etc) than you should protect them as well and you don't always have to put them at the top. I said I liked it. For SQL-injections you should really be using PDO with parametrized queries instead...

Comment: @phihag filter_input_array type can be:"INPUT_GET, INPUT_POST, INPUT_COOKIE, INPUT_SERVER, or INPUT_ENV."

Answer (score -1):

A better way would be `strip_tags()` and `htmlentities()` before saving to db (if you don't mind some extra bits of data).

However, make sure you have taken other precautions as well to protect against SQL injection, by using `mysql_real_escape_string()` or a prepared statement data-access abstraction layer, such as PDO.

Comment: `strip_tags` unnecessarily modifies valid inputs. Also, you're not answering the question of when to encode.

Comment: @phihag: Thanks for your bit. Care to take a look at [$allowable_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) parameter? It's a matter of personal choice. There is no clear concise answer to his/her question. I believe I answered it the way I like to do it, i.e. BEFORE inserting to db. Thanks for the down vote. ;)

Comment: @Shef No matter what you set `$allowable_tags` to, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code) would come out garbled.

Comment: @phihag: Care to explain why would it?

Comment: @Shef Because `strip_tags` is not invertible, a legitimate input like `a<!--b-->c` will be rendered as `ab`.

Comment: @phihang: Sure it wouldn't `$txt = preg_replace("@<!--@", "#!--#", $txt);$txt = strip_tags($txt);$txt = preg_replace("@#!--#@", "<!--", $txt);`

Comment: @Shef This modified function is still not invertible, the input `!--` now comes out as `<!--`.