# Disabled JavaScript in IE6 still not able to see the script code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I m a beginner. This is more related to different options i was trying to learn.

I just took example

```
    <!--
    document.write("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    //-->
```

It was stated that we should use this  tags to avoid the script display in browser if javascript is disabled. 
So Disabled Javascript By following steps as

Click on the Tools menu
Choose Internet Options... from the menu
Click the Security tab on the Internet Options pop up
Click the Custom Level... button to access your security settings
Scroll almost all the way down to the Scripting section
Select the Enable button for Active scripting
Click OK to finish the process
Click Yes when asked to confirm

```
    document.write("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
```

Then i removed the  tags and now i was expecting that i will be able to see the error that is script

```
    "document.write("<h1>Hello World</h1>");"
```

displayed as it is as Javascript is disabled and tags are removed. But what i see is nothing displayed empty page.
Can some1 help me understand this?

Comment: Where did you declare this code line? Within the head section? If so, the content of the head section will never displayed in the window.

Comment: this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code indicates that the comments are no longer needed. Bit of a legacy thing for when men where men and browsers were rubbish

Comment: yes @reporter i have included in head section ok got it hence not displaying thanku... :)

Comment: Why in the world are you testing/working in IE6?

Comment: @epascarello :) actually some applications in company which i wrk in run perfectly in IE6 so i use that

Comment: @CrabBucket Thnks giving me latest info of CDATA

Comment: @ShilpaGurnani almost every major web company does not support a 11 year old browser, MS does not even do it. http://www.ie6countdown.com/ Reason why the apps work well is because they were written for that browser and probably fail with any modern one. Time for a company to start to upgrade and get with the times. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confused.  Scripts should be enclosed in `<script> script here </script>` tags.  If you need content displaying to people who do not have javascript enabled you can do this by using `<noscript> //stuff to be displayed when javascript disabled </noscript>` tags.

An example in your case would be as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    document.write("<h1>hello world</h1>");
</script>
<noscript>
    <h1>Sorry but your browser does not have javascript enabled</h1>
</noscript>
```

Comment: thnks jon :) i just pasted part of it code, have included <script> tag. And yes <noscript> helps to display message for users who dnt have javascript enabled. _I m expecting that it should show me script as it is if javascript is disabled in IE6_ which m not able to see my page is blank

Comment: You won't see the actual script itself.  Also as someone pointed out in the comments above if your document.write appears in the head section of the document then you will not see this displayed on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The comments inside the script tags

```
<script>
    <!--

    //-->
</script>
```

were for browsers that did not understand what a `<script>` tag is. You are talking about Netscape 1, any book that teaches you this stuff and uses document.write is out dated.

Comment: ok... actually i was referring http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/ for online tutorial. Thanks will search for better1. will be glad if u suggest some :)