# Do we still need <!-- //--> in JavaScript block

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using HTML comment tag <!— --> still relevant around JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code)

Kind of remember `<!-- //-->` is used to prevent JavaScript code from being displayed in a lower version of IE. Anyone can provide a link to the article explaining this? Hard to search "`<!--`" in Google, because it's got stripped off.

And do we still need this  in JavaScript block?

Thanks!

Comment: Lower version of IE? You mean IE1 and IE2? IE implemented JavaScript in IE3.

Comment: This is answered here: [Using HTML comment tag <!— --> still relevant around JavaScript code?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1508005/354776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those comments were used when Javascript was first introduced. They are not needed any more, and haven't been for quite a while.

The purpose was to hide the script from browsers that didn't even know what the `script` tag was for. Those browsers would ignore the script tag and show the code inside as regular HTML content.

There are no browsers left that don't know about the `<script>` tag, so even if they don't run the script, they still don't show the code inside.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you're worried about time-travellers from somewhere back in last milennium coming to the present day with their old computers.