# how to redirect user from php file back to `index.html` on dreamhost

Tags: php, redirect

I'm setting up a simple landing page on DreamHost.  It won't let me put php code in the file `index.html`.  So, when user submits an email address, I use `$_POST` to submit the email address to another page `mail_auto.php`.

After seeing a quick "email sent" message, I'd like the user to be directed back to the `index.html` page from `mail_auto.php`.

`header()` looks a bit complex and seems to interfere with the execution of the balance of `mail_auto.php`.

What's the best way to redirect the user?

Comment: `header()` isn't complex at all, use it like this `header('Location: index.html');`

Comment: `header("Location: index.html");` is the simplest way to redirect someone on the server side. What problems are you encountering with it?

Comment: @StevenVondruska ,  I haven't had a problem yet, but the manuel seems to suggest I have to put the `header()` at the beginning of the script.  So, my concern is the balance of the script won't get executed.

Comment: You can put `header()` anywhere in the script. The trick is that you cannot send any content before you call `header()`. So you can't do something like `echo "hello world"; header("Location: index.html");`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To redirect user back to index.html, use the following:

```
header('Location: index.html');
exit;
```

Alternatively, if you want to display something like " Redirecting... " on screen, you can use the `meta-refresh` method , or JavaScript `window.location` method with `setTimeout`

The meta refresh method:

Add this to HTML `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=index.html">
```

where 2 is number of seconds before the refresh is executed.

Answer (score 3):

Using the header is typically what I'd do.

Have you thought about using JavaScript? It's not the best way, although it would work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
   window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
   //-->
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript can be disabled by user.

Comment: I agree, which is why I stated it wasn't the best way. Using php with header('Location: index.html') would be the preferred way, although the user stated it was causing interference with their code.

Comment: Commenting JS code like that is for [ancient browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code) ...

Answer (score 2):

Just echo this javascript code end of the process.

```
    <script>
      window.location.href = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com';
    </script>
```

Comment: What if Javascript is disabled ?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://www.yourwebsite.com/'"> content means time , yes Shivan this is an alternative solution.

Comment: Meta refresh is a sloppy solution