# Can't get php array through ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I can't get the values from a php array thru ajax.
My php array is made of the values of a query.

This is my **php** code:

```
<?php
    $conn = oci_connect("admin", "admin", "localhost/XE");
    $query = "SELECT COD_PROVEEDOR, NOMBRE FROM PROVEEDOR";
    $exec= oci_parse($conn, $query);
    $resultado = oci_execute($exec);
    $exec= oci_fetch_array($exec, OCI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($exec);
?>
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "agrega_producto.php", 
        type : "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success : function(data){
            //data = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(data, function(index, data){
            $('#proveedor').append("<option value='" + data.COD_PROVEEDOR + "'>" + data.NOMBRE + "</option>"); 
            });
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

I always get empty data. There's no way I found to make it work

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive about the problem i.e. what errors you get or what's happening vs the expected result? PS `<!-- -->` isn't the correct comment syntax in JavaScript.

Comment: Are those HTML comment tags within JavaScript? Try `console.log(data)` and see what it returns.

Comment: why cant you simply `//` to comment that js line?

Comment: What Dave said, with the code shown there could be any number of errors, including database errors or connection problems.

Comment: [<!-- -->](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code) not valid comment in js.Comment in js is `//` --> for a line and for a block `/* ............. */`

Comment: Comment syntax in JS are wrong like others mentioned mentioned. If you are certain the PHP code is echoing valid JSON data, perhaps you aren't setting the `Content-type` response header in your HTTP response. In your PHP, try `header('Content-type: application/json')`. Use Dev Tools/Firebug to see what headers and body your request is returning.