# JavaScript relative page redirecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-redirect, redirect

So, I want to change my tumblr url and redirect everyone from my old one to the new one, *but* I want them to be redirected to the post they were linked to, for example /post/64948618646.
I'm quite fond of this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
   window.location="http://someurl.tumblr.com";
//-->
</script>
```

so is it possible to somehow get this like **http://oldurl.tumblr.com/post/64948618646** redirect not only to **http://newurl.tumblr.com** but also ***http://newurl.tumblr.com/post/64948618646***?

Comment: For the love of *[insert preferred deity]* please don't use `<!-- //-->` in between your script tags.  Which ever site you found the code on, best not to go there ever again =)

Comment: @Emissary Apparently there is one reason to still do that. A comment on http://stackoverflow.com/a/1508005/86515 asserts that googlebot will follow things that look like links in javascript unless it's commented out.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG There's no credible source - just a link to an inconclusive forum debate.  In any case, even if it were true why would you not put the comment above/outside the `<script>` tag?  *HTML* `<!--` comments are not valid Javascript statements - ordinarily the interpreter will choke, it's just the browser/s that let you off with it for the sake of legacy code - but this behaviour is non-standard (and not future proof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would probably get away with:

```
window.location.href = "http://new-url.com" + window.location.pathname;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with Tumbler, but I am going to assume the last number in the URL you provided is a GET value.  If so, and you are using PHP, find the GET variable name and use the following:

```
$post_number = $_GET["variable_name"];
```

Then in JavaScript, grab the post number

```
var post_number = <?php echo $post_number; ?>;
var url = "http://someurl.tumblr.com/post/" + post_number;
window.location = url;
```