# Javascript tag having <!-- -->

Tags: javascript

I've been seen some javascript coding enclose with `<!-- -->`. Is there any significant having it that way?

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
      ...javascript code here
-->
</script>
```

Compared to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

      ...javascript code here

</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code

Comment: You don't need the `language` attribute either. Your sources for this code are pretty old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used to be put as a fallback for browsers that didn't support javascript. You might find the answers to this question interesting: [Are HTML comments inside script tags a best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808816/are-html-comments-inside-script-tags-a-best-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is ok to have because you are using javascript in the Html file so the comment using `<!---->` works only on html file so its fine, but if you was using a external .js file you couldn't use this method of comment because this is the commenting tag for HTML and not javascript.