# Why does <!-- return undefined and not a syntax error?

Tags: javascript

The html comment tags `<!--` & `-->` return `undefined` when run as a js command, I expected a syntax error. Why does this happen ?

I stumbled upon this in [DoubleClick ...](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/156583?hl=en) (the [download](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_166E5C7D248A10CAB2180D1E3204A2A3EDDB_2621920_en_v4) link).

Comment: I think it's because in the old days when not every browser supported JS it was advised to wrap the contents of inline `<scipt>` elements in HTML comments to prevent them from being rendered as text in a browser that didn't recognize the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Using HTML comment tag <!— --> still relevant around JavaScript code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `<script>` was added to HTML as an afterthought, and at the time MANY browsers didn't acknowledge the existence of scripts, `<!--` is actually a defined member of the Javascript language spec, and is treated as "start of comment".

Remember that by default, browsers ignore tags that they do not understand, so that

```
<tag_which_does_not_exist>hi there</tag_which_does_not_exist>
```

would actually display "hi there" in a browser. For script-unaware browsers, that'd mean they'd actuall display the JS code as text in the document. So..

```
<script>
<!--
alert('hi there');
// --> 
</script>
```

would pop up a JS alert in script-aware browsers, and would be completely ignored by script-ignorant browsers.

Also note that `-->` is NOT valid Javascript, which is why it has to be entered as `// -->`. `//` is the other JS single-line comment, and it comments out the otherwise invalid `-->` html end-of-comment tag.