# Why use <!-- //--> inside script

Tags: javascript, php

I have several  tags that looks like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
some function inside here
//-->
</script>
```

What are the `<!--` and `//-->` doing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808816/are-html-comments-inside-script-tags-a-best-practice

Comment: Check this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code

Comment: <!--
some function inside here
-->

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply's, and sorry for posting a duplicate.