# One-line "<!--" comments in JavaScript and ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, ecma262

In the previous century, there was a popular "hack" to hide JavaScript from non-JavaScript-enabled browsers:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    <!--
    alert("Hello, World!");
    // --> Your browser doesn't support JavaScript
</script>
```

Despite `<!--` is explained to be just a single-line JavaScript comment in a number of [tutorials](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/comments.htm), it is not mentioned anywhere in ECMAScript standard (see [7.4 Comments](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.4)). While being non-standard, this type of comment is supported by all modern browsers, so you can actually comment out any JavaScript code with it:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    <!-- alert("Hello, World!");
    <!-- This is a comment
    <!-- This is another comment
    <!-- This is yet another comment
</script>
```

Still, there's one exception: the `eval()` function. The following code works correctly in Communicator 4.x/Mozilla/Opera(Presto)/Safari/Chrome, but causes a syntax error in MSIE:

```
<form action = "#">
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function testEval() {
            var s = "<!--\n";
            s += "alert(\"eval() invoked\");\n";
            s += "// -->"
            eval(s);
        }
    </script>
    <input type = "button" value = "Test eval()" onclick = "testEval();"/>
</form>
```

Basically, unlike all other browsers, MSIE fails at `eval("<!--")`.

2 questions:

- What is the status of `<!--` in JavaScript? Is it defined in any (even outdated) JavaScript specs/documents? Or are modern browsers just preserving some sort of bug-by-bug compatibility? **Edit**: this has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842628).
- Do you have any idea why is MSIE/Trident different? Particularly, should this custom behaviour (of `eval()` function) be reported as a bug to Microsoft?

Comment: Why do you want to comment out javascript in a browser when it is not enabled?

Comment: This time, IE is right. `<!--` is a syntax error. But since `<script>` is an element with a `text` node, which contains the code, the HTML parser removes the content from the DOM. (If I'm wrong, please, kindly correct me)

Comment: The 1st question is indeed a duplicate. I still would appreciate any feedback about MSIE eval() issue

Comment: @FelixKling It isn't *entirely* duplicated. The question also asks why IE is different.

Comment: @Ismael: Sure, but I could argue that a question should be a *single* question, not two. Also the other answer makes it clear (I hope) that this is a deprecated, non-standard browser feature. Either IE simply stopped supporting it or it never did.

Comment: @FelixKling I think it was an accidental feature. But still, this is asking about a behaviour with a language constructor that isn't covered in the other question.

Comment: @Ismael: Then either the whole post should be reduced to that question or a new question should be posted. However, I doubt that anybody who does not work on IE can answer that question.

Comment: @FelixKling Lets see what the O.P. does. Reducing the question would be a great idea. But, at the moment, it is arguably in the 'grey-zone': it is a duplicated and it isn't.

Comment: @nils — So that if the browser doesn't recognise the `<script>` element at all (e.g. if it is Netscape 1.0) then it won't treat the script as text to be displayed to the user. (It's pointless this century).

Comment: My guess is that IE only treats `<!--` inside `<script>` elements in a special way, because that's the only place where they *could* make sense. They don't make sense in arbitrary JS code (e.g. in `eval`), and I would assume (though I cannot test it) that you would also get a syntax error if you included the code as script `src`. However, I'm not working on IE nor do I know anybody who does, so this really is just a guess.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't think it treats any differently. `<script><!-- a --></script>` and `<div><!-- a --></div>` will be parsed by the HTML parser as `<script></script>` and `<script></script>`. Since an empty `<script>` isn't invalid HTML and isn't invalid Javascript, everything goes fine without errors. When running `eval('<!--');`, the Javascript engine expects pure Javascript. This is my wild guess. And assumind that IE doesn't suck (much).

Comment: @Ismael: But the point is that `<!--` inside a `<script>` element is actually interpreted by the JS engine, not by the HTML parser. Note how the examples don't have a closing `-->`. The other question explains that `<!--` are treated as single line comments in JS.

Comment: @FelixKling Then I was **really** wrong. I think that IE had some troubles with `eval()` in the past. Notive that `Function('<!--')()` gives a syntax error in IE11 (just like with `eval()`). But since this is deprecated, there's no problem. The browsers aren't required to have deprecated functionality, I guess.