# <script> Invalid comment formatting?

Tags: javascript

I have taken on a project that someone else has worked on and I am running into a bunch of script blocks formatted like this:

```
<script>
<!--
$('...').live('change', function() {
    if (...) {
        $('...').hide();
        $('...').show();
    } else {
        $('...').show();
        $('...').hide();
    }
});
//-->
</script>
```

They are not even the correct comment format for JavaScript.
The code still works but should I worry that this might break in the long term if I start adding to it?

Is this just blatantly wrong and should I remove all the invalid comments?

Comment: It's the old-school way of commenting out JS for browsers that didn't support it. It's pretty way-old and useless now.

Comment: Back in the days this was to prevent JavaScript code from showing up in browsers that do not support JS. It is valid.

Comment: Ahhh that makes since the project is like 8 years old or something so that explains it.

Comment: Pretty much what Dave Newton said. I wouldn't move it to an include file, that is for sure.

Comment: @NooBskie Fun fact: If you open up the console (developer tools) and type in `<!--`, it will get executed perfectly fine.

Comment: RIP the two answers below. :D

Comment: Learn something new everyday;)

Comment: @NiCkNewman haha right

Comment: actually, fun fact, that's a valid comment in JS. any resemblance to the old-school XHTML comment is coincidental. ok, not really, but it _is_ valid JS, even node.js and external browser scripts...

Comment: Come on~ This is not a duplicate question. It may have the same answer but the intention was way different.

Comment: @DanielCheung It's probably a dupe, the question I eventually found and linked to is a better dupe though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To formalize my comment.

Back in the day not all browsers supported JavaScript. To make the JS disappear it would be wrapped in an HTML comment and the browser would effectively ignore it.

This hasn't been relevant for some time now and it can be safely deleted.

It can also be left in without harm, but ew.

By way of example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1507939/438992) from 2009 asks the question re: relevancy, not what it actually is.

This also means I'm old :(