# Tag end comment --> in javascript like text for web speed

Tags: javascript, tags, comments

I need to put this " --> " like text for web speed in javascript function . For example:

```
function PutText() 
{
    var cntrlContent = "<div>"+
                         "<!--WSS " +  
                         " Este es código Progress y su terminador es: "+
                         " --> " +    
                       "</div>"; 
}
```

It is a error because "-->" is interpreted like comments tags "" all sintaxis aftes is incorrect. But really i need use this "-->" text.

Any help??

Comment: what is the error you are facing?

Comment: What kind of archaic browser are you using that you have to use the HTML comments in Javascript? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code

Comment: Sorry i modified the question, beacuse i didn´t expalin all. I need insert web speed code like text.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more than likely with just the greater than symbol. Use the HTML Code for greater than.

```
 function PutText() 
 {
     var cntrlContent = "<div>"+
                     " Este en --&gt ejemplo" +    
                   "</div>"; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't place HTML comments inside tags.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function try this:

```
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerText = "Este en --> ejemplo";
```

You can append the div to any other element you want like this:

```
element.appendChild(div);
```