# Chrome blocking JavaScript for a roll-over effect

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, rollover, rollover-effect

Having a bit of a confusing time trying to resolve an issue with some JavaScript code I've inherited from a previous edition of a site we're updating.

Essentially, the JS gives an image a roll-over effect when hovering, but on Chrome, this is blocked, and I can't seem to figure out what would be causing this.

Not an expert in JS by any means, just trying to get this resolved across all browser-types, so here's the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    <!--
                    function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
                      var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
                        d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
                      if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
                      for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
                      if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
                    }
                    function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
                      var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
                       if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
                    }
                    function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
                      var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
                        var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                        if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
                    }
                    -->
                </script>
```

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: Are those HTML comments intentional?

Comment: [Using HTML comment tag <!— --> still relevant around JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code)

Comment: Jordy this code is unnecessarily complex for the use case. If this is not part of some builder and can be deleted and rewritten normally, I would recommend doing so.

Comment: Also if you want someone to close look at this code I'd format it. Too dense no indents and line breaks.

Comment: Oh wow, "MM_" was prefix for Macromedia Dreamweaver (or maybe Fireworks, depending on the exporting app). I'm guessing this is a copy/paste of some really old JavaScript, strictly based on the "MM_" prefix.

Answer (score -1):

are you using antivirus ?
try disable antivirus and run again.
maybe antivirus blocked the script

Comment: Welcome to SO, this was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be a comment.

Comment: why would a person disable the antivirus..? **never do this**