# Valid comment in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and encountered this:

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
document.write("Hi!");
//-->
</script>
</head>
```

is this a valid way of commenting and why is it being used?

Comment: @Alex this is a terrible tip. The technique hasn't been needed for over a decade now. I heartily advise against following that.

Comment: @VLAZ Below is a  **Note: The two forward slashes at the end of comment line (//) is the JavaScript comment symbol. This prevents JavaScript from executing the --> tag.**

I thought this is good to know but well there will be other resources which explains this .

Comment: @Alex Again, this is *exceptionally outdated*. Doesn't matter how you write it, it's plain unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an [HTML comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment) and the use of this format in script harks back to the '90s where some browsers did not understand JavaScript so we have to HIDE the JS from those browsers

Typically

```html
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- // hide from older browsers
document.write("Yes we have no bananas"); // this will be written if the browser understands JS
// --></script>
```

It is IGNORED as a comment in JS so the contents will be executed

UNLESS the code is right after the `<--`

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- document.write("No we have no bananas"); // this will NOT be written since it is treated as a comment in JS too
// --></script>
```

You will see that the end comment is commented in JS too so it is not seen as minus minus greater than `// -->`

The VALID multiline comment in JS is

```
/* these are
   comments */
```

and a single line comment is

```
// here is one comment
```

[More information from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Comments)

More from SO: [Using HTML comment tag <!-- --> still relevant around JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507939/using-html-comment-tag-still-relevant-around-javascript-code)